# jQuery scrollTo plugin doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scrollto

I have been at this for hours now and I simply cannot figure it out.

Basically, I have a long list of items that gets populated way down the page. When the user clicks on one of these items, I want to scroll the window back to the very top where the content will be loaded (arguably poor design, I know, but that is a separate issue).

Here are what my scripts look like:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/jquery.jgrowl.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/javascript.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/supersized.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/effects.core.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js'></script>
```

Here is the HTML of the top of my page:

```
<div id='header'>
<div id='pagetop'></div>
</div>
```

And this is the call that fails:

```
$.scrollTo('#pagetop',800)
```

It does not produce an error message when I attempt to run this line, so I know scrollTo is being loaded properly, but when I make the call, it simply does nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a link to the page or more page content to help troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: @experimentX I do not get any errors

Comment: is this the plugin http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: @experimentX Yes, that is the plugin I am using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery doesn't have a `scrollTo` method. But you can use [`.scrollTop()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) on an object.

```
$('#pagetop').scrollTop(800);
```

**Update**

If you just want an element to scroll into view, you can use the native DOM method:

```
$('#pagetop')[0].scrollIntoView();
```

or even

```
document.getElementById('pagetop').scrollIntoView();
```

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/UHhDT/

**Update 2**

jQuerys `scrollTop` can also be used in `.animate()`.

```
$(document.body).animate({scrollTop: $('#pagetop').offset().top}, 2000);
```

For instance:

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/UHhDT/1/

Comment: .scrollTop() does not work either. No errors or anything, simply nothing happens. Also, scrollTo is a jQuery plugin available here: http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Comment: @James: well you should have mentioned that you're using that plugin.

Comment: The .scrollIntoView method seemed to do what everything else was incapable of doing. For all practical purposes, this is what I was looking for, but for designs sake, let's say I wanted it do to a sliding animation to make it look nice, how would I do that?

For clarification: I basically want to force the user to scroll to the top of the page, I am not moving any elements around.

Thank you.

Comment: @jAndy Sorry, I thought that was implied by the jquery-plugins and scrollto tags

Comment: @James: to smooth scroll, you combine `.animate()` and `scrollTop`, see update2. And oh.. it looked like experimentX added those tags later on.

Comment: @jAndy Thank you very much for your explanation. For some reason, your method for smooth scrolling is not working for me, but you have helped a lot as is and I hesitate to ask for more guidance.

Comment: jAndy: Seems rather strange, but your last scrolling solution only works in Chrome and does not work in Firefox/Opera (can't test in IE on my mac)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)